# Blazor "No element is currently associated with component {n}" error, but only in production

Tags: c#, iis, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

My site is hosted from a .Net 5 web service running in IIS, and that all works fine. But I have a series of pages that work as a search page to view a list of results, then a "View More Details" button for each of the results that links to a details page. When I am running the app in  development environment everything works fine, and in production I can confirm that the data is being retrieved properly via an API call to my web service in the `OnInitializedAsync()` method, I see the data in the Network tab and I even tried printing it to the console to be sure, and it is there and is correct, and  is even being deserialized correctly. But the app throws the error "Error: No element is currently associated with component 159" (159 is one of them, it shows multiple numbers as this error shows up many times in the browser console). This error only happens when it is running in a production environment. My issue is that when the page loads and all of the data is there, none of it is displayed, and none of the components get updated. Why would this work fine in a development environment but crash in production. Is this a known issue, or have I probably made some kind of a mistake somewhere?

I understand that this error means that a component is referenced but is actually null, or I tried to display data from a C# variable in the page, but that variable is null. But why is it null, my data is there, it shouldn't be null. I would post the raw data result, but it has sensitive information in it and so I can't. But what has me most confused is that there are multiple pages that follow this same concept and they all seem to be working fine, except for this one.

I guess it would help for me to be able to tell which component is "not currently associated" with the element. But I couldn't find anything to tell me which component is giving me trouble. Would anybody be able to point me in the right direction there?

Much thanks in advance!

P.S. I am not looking for somebody to solve the issue for me, but if somebody has seen this before, then a nudge in the right direction would be ideal.

Comment: in your development environment, do you run it with IIS as well, or directly? i've found that IIS is a potential source of hard to debug, obscure problems.

Comment: I just tested it by running it from the command line "dotnet run" and it fails there too. I guess the only time that it does work is when I run it from Visual Studio 2019 using IIS Express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I discovered the problem. I had to comment out individual components and republish the site about 20+ times to narrow down which component it was that was causing the issue. I have another service running on our network that allows users to access different printers that aren't normally available on a network, and I store references to those printers in the database. The page I was loading pulls up a list of the printers and that list was null in the production environment because it uses a different instance of Google Chrome, meaning that the list that is stored in `localStorage` never was downloaded and stored until I navigated to the page that downloads the list. So a simple `if ({list} != null)` at the beginning of that component block solved my problem. Rookie mistake, but thanks to anybody that looked into this for me!